# SAML Response - What needs to be verified to ensure the response can be trusted?

Tags: azure, saml, saml-2.0

Apologies if these seems like a duplicate but I have been searching through the posts and I cannot find exactly what I am looking for.

My web application is sending an auth request to Azure for Single Sign On. Upon receipt of the response, what field and attributes need to be verified to ensure that the assertions can be trusted and why?

An example response is here from the Microsoft documentation-

```
<samlp:Response ID="_a4958bfd-e107-4e67-b06d-0d85ade2e76a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T07:38:15.144Z" Destination="https://contoso.com/identity/inboundsso.aspx" InResponseTo="id758d0ef385634593a77bdf7e632984b6" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> https://login.microsoftonline.com/82869000-6ad1-48f0-8171-272ed18796e9/</Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    ...
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <Assertion ID="_bf9c623d-cc20-407a-9a59-c2d0aee84d12" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T07:38:15.144Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/82869000-6ad1-48f0-8171-272ed18796e9/</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      ...
    </ds:Signature>
    <Subject>
      <NameID>Uz2Pqz1X7pxe4XLWxV9KJQ+n59d573SepSAkuYKSde8=</NameID>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id758d0ef385634593a77bdf7e632984b6" NotOnOrAfter="2013-03-18T07:43:15.144Z" Recipient="https://contoso.com/identity/inboundsso.aspx" />
      </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2013-03-18T07:38:15.128Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-03-18T08:48:15.128Z">
      <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>https://www.contoso.com</Audience>
      </AudienceRestriction>
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
        <AttributeValue>testuser@contoso.com</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
        <AttributeValue>3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
      ...
    </AttributeStatement>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-03-18T07:33:56.000Z" SessionIndex="_bf9c623d-cc20-407a-9a59-c2d0aee84d12">
      <AuthnContext>
        <AuthnContextClassRef> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

**What i know so far.**

- You must verify the signature to ensure the message has not been modified.
- You must verify that the certificate public key is from a trusted source or else any validly signed certificate would authenticate.

What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The signature - remember to [check the references](https://coding.abel.nu/2015/12/xml-signatures-and-references/).
- Verify that the certificate is from the right peer (as you've noticed yourself)
- The Conditions of the assertion.

I'd recommend that you do not write your own code for this and instead use an existing SAML2 SP library. Getting all of this right is a lot of work (I've done it, and I'm not sure I would if I had known how much work it is).

Comment: Anders is too modest to mention his own library https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices. If you dig under the covers in that library, you can find the modules to directly validate and unpack the tokens - if you need to - or just let the library do all the work for the site if that fits. It's excellent and I use it in production on several systems.

Comment: Thank you for linking for information about checking the references I found it very insightful - Definitely a check that i missed!